# Flutter, is it bad habit to use MediaQuery for sizing every widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I almost use like

```
double number = 0.2;
someWidgetSize : MediaQuery.of(context).size."width or height" * number
```

for every widgets

but suddenly I thought that it is too easy to make widgets for all device screen sizes

so I`m just curious is it bad habits?(it may have side effects or something)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No. There is no side effects about this.**

We all do this when it is important to have a dynamic widget size. Just be aware that this uses the device size. If you want to use the parent widget's dize use `LayoutBuilder` widget that gives you the constraints of the parent wiget.